# how to call a function with a pointer as its argument

Tags: c, pointers, exception, multidimensional-array

what is problem? i want send a multi-dimensional pointer to a function as its arguments. But i got this error

Exception thrown at 0x00007FF770A92231 in Check nevis.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000400000007.

what did i do wrong? and what this error means?

```
#include <stdio.h>
test(int *ptr)
{
    printf("%d", *(*(ptr+1)+1));
}
int main()
{
    int a[2][3] = { { 1,2,3 }, { 4,5,6 } };
    int(*ptr)[2][3]=&a;
    test(ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: with an int* pointer, you can't use * twice on it! What did you want to print?

Comment: i want print 5.

Comment: Asadiyan, what return type do you want for `test()`?

Comment: `int(*ptr)[2][3]=&a;` should most likely be just `int** ptr = a`

Comment: then your function should be on int** to access the 2 dimensions

Comment: why? i want function be void and why i should do this.

Comment: Not function, but function parameter.

Comment: i did this and i got error again

Comment: @B.Go most certainly not.

Answer (score -1):

You need to have pointer to pointer to int:

```
void test(int **ptr)
{
    printf("%d", ptr[1][1]);
}

int main()
{
    int a[2][3] = { { 1,2,3 }, { 4,5,6 } };
    int **ptr = a;
    test(ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Note: it is expected and good practice to prefix the function, which returns nothing, with 'void'. Probably you got a warning about it - NEVER ignore warnings!

Comment: what is difference between ptr[1][1] and *(*(ptr+1))

Comment: i tried the code and i got the same error again

Comment: and the same location?

Comment: i gotException thrown at 0x00007FF6CB422243 in Check nevis.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000400000007

Comment: Did you change the main() function as sugested, too?

Comment: no i didnt change main function

Comment: So you have an answer. The int(*ptr)[2][3]=&a; means that you try to write address of array 'a' into element [2][3] of an unknown (unallocated) array, pointed by 'ptr'. It is wrong. Change this line as suggested.

Comment: no i want value

Comment: What value??????????? Try do this, as suggested, and you will see that it works as you want. BTW: there is NO element [2][3] - this is indice range, it means that maximum indices are 1 and 2.

Comment: `int **ptr` **most certainly** is **not** compatible with `int (*)[3]`

Comment: And `*(*(ptr + 1))` is the same as `ptr[1][0]`, not the other way round.

Comment: Of course. Should be? Your array is an array of two 3-element subarrays, so the first '*' makes pointer to the subarray, the second '*' makes pointer to subarray element.

Comment: About indices order: you are right, my mistake.

Comment: No, it dont work i tried all of ur suggestions